# What's the best way to rewrite this?

Tags: javascript, filter

I've wrote search query filter, but it seems complicated and long to me and I suppose there's another way to write it. So could you show your example?

```
return this.myCourses.filter(c => {
    return c?.purchased_course?.title.toLowerCase().startsWith(this.searchQuery) ||
      c?.purchased_course?.user?.first_name.toLowerCase().startsWith(this.searchQuery) ||
      c?.purchased_course?.user?.last_name.toLowerCase().startsWith(this.searchQuery)
  })
```

Comment: If this code work it's not that the place for this question use instead https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Something like this ?
`this.myCourses.filter(course => [c?.purchased_course?.title, c?.purchased_course?.user?.first_name, c?.purchased_course?.user?.last_name].any(textStartsWith.bind(this.searchQuery)));`
Helper function :
`function textStartsWith(text) { return typeof text === "string" && text.startsWith(this); }`

Answer (score 0):

[Object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring)

Unpack fields from objects passed as a function parameter.

```js
const startsWithQuery = p => p?.toLowerCase().startsWith(this.searchQuery);

return this.myCourses.filter(({purchased_course: {title, user: {first_name, last_name} = {}}}) => [title, first_name, last_name].some(startsWithQuery));
```